# Borrar el cache dependiendo de la vista con $ionicHistory.clearCache()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

hay una forma de eliminar el caché de la vista que uno quiera?, por ejemplo en el javascript quiero eliminar el cache del siguiente vista que quiero, para que actulize la información de todos los productos, pero en otra vista regresa a la vista productos y en ese momento no quiero eliminar cache, solo que elimine el cahce a dar click en un botón, ya intenté colocar $ionicHistory.clearCache(), pero no elimina e caché, solo si se coloca el cache-view="false":

```
<ion-view view-title="productos-view" cache-view="false">
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si, de esta manera :

```
 $state.go('app_location', {}, {location: 'replace'})
```

Donde `app_location` debes reemplazarlo por el nombre de tu `state` asi cuando vuelvas con el button back esta no guardara el cache si no que refrescara la vista.

Otra opcion es que utilices :

```
$scope.$on("$ionicView.beforeEnter", function(event, data){

})
```

Esto hara que antes de que entre a tu vista ejecutes codigo por lo tanto ahi podrias refrescar la informacion.

Comment: hola muchas gracias, sobre $ionicView.beforeEnter eso se coloca donde la vista se actualiza?

Comment: Eso se pone en el controlador de tu state me imagino que tienes alguna funcion que se encarga de traer los productos entonces dentro de ese metodo llamas a la funcion

Comment: la busqueda de los productos está en el controlador, no está en una función aparte, 'entonces me tocaría hacer una función que busque los productos de un servicio?

Comment: Nooo!! Esta bien que este en una funcion, te digo que esa funcion la llames desde el beforeView para que cuando vuelva a cargarse tu vista, se reflejen los cambios que hiciste

Comment: mmm vale, si sirve al momento de actualizar, pero hay una forma que yo pueda decir que se actulize o no ? osea decir que descative el cache y luego que se active

Comment: Mmm... cual seria esa necesidad? Dime el caso particular

Comment: formule un poco mala pregunta pero si me diste la repsuesta, muchas gracias. Sobre lo que dije antes, por ejemplo en una vista da click en ver todos los productos ahi debe estar desactivado el cache para que se actualize los productos, escoge un producto y al dar click entra otra vista me muestra la información del producto y hay un boton de regresar al dar click vuelve al producto donde vio la información y eso se activa el cache para que quede en la posicion que está. Los productos se visualizan con tindercards.

Comment: Nunca he trabajado con tindercards, sin embargo si es que te sirve puedes recibir un parametro supongamos con valor 1 y 2 (en tu vista que lista los productos) si recibe 1 quiere decir que entro por primera vez (por ejemplo del menu) y no hace nada solo muestra, sin embargo si recibe 2 quiere decir que ya entro, se selecciono un producto (por ende debes saber la id o algo que lo identifique) y si es asi recuperar ese producto y asi vuelves al mismo

Comment: vale muchas gracias.